# Periodic trends on half cell potentials

Tags: physical-chemistry, oxidation-state, periodic-trends, reduction-potential

In a practice examination that I'm using to study for my upcoming midterm, one of the questions asks to choose three elements from a row of the periodic table and to give the order of the increasing oxidation half cell potential of the neutral element. Is it correct to assume that a more electronegative element would have the lowest half cell oxidation potential? Because it would be the most resistant to losing its electrons?

Would a correct sequence (highest oxidation half cell potential to lowest) be B, C, N because as the sequence goes from left to right it becomes increasingly electronegative and therefore less likely to be oxidized?

Comment: https://www.google.co.in/search?q=electrochemical+series&espv=2&biw=1440&bih=803&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiUjLnF_LrSAhXIPI8KHdkaACEQ_AUIBigB#imgrc=p2M3BgmtGk2ChM:

Comment: No, it's much more complicated, in general.